# SFML 2.4.2 Co-ordinate system offset

Tags: c++, coordinates, sfml

I am writing a small program using SFML which draws a 5 x 5 rectangle at any point specified by clicking the mouse.

I am using mapPixelToCoords() to map the mouse coordinates to the pixels as recommended in the documentation, however I am still encountering a weird offset between the coordinates and the actual shape which is drawn. 
The offset varies on different parts of the window (it is not a constant x,y value).

I would like the rectangle to be drawn precisely under the mouse pointer, how do I go about removing this offset?

This is the code I'm using to draw the rectangle on click:
[Screenshot of offset in the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D69nv.png)

```
int main(){

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 720), "SFML window");

    sf::Event event;

    //Rectangle to be drawn on the screen
    sf::RectangleShape someRect;
    someRect.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    someRect.setSize({ 5, 5 });
    someRect.setPosition(100, 120);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
            if (!windowStarted) {
                    event.type = sf::Event::Closed;
            }

            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                    // Close window: exit
                    if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                            window.close();
                    }

                    if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                            someRect.setPosition(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));
                    }
            }

            window.clear(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));

            window.draw(someRect);

            window.display();

    }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the images, it's an obvious scaling mismatch between the window view and the physical mouse co-ordinates.  I predict the largest offset near the upper-right corner and near perfect alignment in the lower-left. Are you running in an odd graphics mode that doesn't fit your screen well?  Could be a bug in the library, but it's more likely a configuration issue.  The library just doesn't have the right scale factors for the window port dimensions.

Comment: Are you running your display at any scaling other than 100% dpi? SFML doesn't handle all cases of high resolution displays properly so far. Other than that the code runs perfectly fine for me (100% scaling).

Comment: As a side note, you should just use the mouse coordinates provided inside `sf::Event` rather than polling them again.